# Java 8, как исходя из значения некоторой переменной определить принцип работы части кода?

Tags: java, java-8

Представим у нас есть программа, которая при запуске читает конфиг и устанавливает внутри себя параметры. у нас есть boolean переменная в конфиге, в зависимости от значения которой программа определяет какую функцию использовать. это можно решить через абстрактный класс и двух его классов реализующих, вызывая в них функцию, но может есть более изящный подход? чтобы не каждый раз проверять эту переменую, а вообще выбросить её, чтобы функция вырбалась изходя из значения перемнной раз и навсегда

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: "чтобы не каждый раз проверять эту переменую, а вообще выбросить её, чтобы функция вырбалась изходя из значения перемнной" - если выбросить переменную, что исходя из какого значения что-то выбирать?

Comment: если у вас есть спринг или любой подобный фреймворк (имеется  в виду DI), то делаете реализации бинами, рисуете интерфейс и на бины одеваете dependon , в котором указываете данное свойство. вот и все, в интерфейс инжектится нужный бин

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверяйте опцию один раз при старте приложения:

```
interface MyFunction() {
    void f();
}

class OptionEnabled implements MyFunction {
    public void f() {
        // реализация для варианта, когда опция включена
    }
}

class OptionDisabled implements MyFunction {
    public void f() {
        // реализация для варианта, когда опция выключена
    }
}

// При старте программы выбираем функцию раз и навсегда

final MyFunction function = null;

if (optionEnabledInConfig()) {
    function = new OptionEnabled();
} else {
    function = new OptionDisabled();
}

// далее по коду используете function

function.f();
```

Естественно, интерфейс и классы нужно назвать, чтоб они отражали суть происходящего. Тут я назвал их абстрактно, так как они фигурируют в вопросе.